# Can I use a boot hard drive with different computers?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, drivers, multiple-computers

I am wanting to use a hard drive that is a boot drive with multiple computers.
 The computers would boot to this hard drive and both computers are different in every way.
 Is it possible to do this by having the proper drivers installed that both systems need?

Comment: You will encounter problems if you don't SysPrep the installation or use third-party image tools that allows for restoration on dissimilar hardware before you move the HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 installed, there is a good chance that your drive will **just work**™ with another set of hardware.

You can install all drivers that both systems might need. That being said, conflicting drivers might cause unstable system performance. Boot up your system in your new hardware configuration and test it out.

---

On a side note, Windows 10 is known to have licensing issues when there is too much hardware change in your system. You might end up losing your license for Windows 10.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 without a license.

Comment: @UnknownLuck - You should purchase a license.  Windows is a paid product.  We won't be able to help you with any problems caused by you not having a license for Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, right now I am not concerned with buying a license but I will buy in the future.

Comment: I've done something similar with Win98 numerous times, without problem.  When I got a job in the IT field, work typically found it problematic.  However, work also used WinXP and had a habit of installing as many specialized drivers as they could.  Our leaders said it couldn't be done, and blamed XP.  But once they ended up trying this on a system with pretty generic drivers, and they were surprised at how well it worked.  There are entire Linux distros with boot CDs designed to work on lots of hardware. So it'll probably work as long as you have available (preferably flexible/generic) drivers

Comment: @UnknownLuck : You do know that the Win10 upgrade process is fabulously cheap (free!) now, but that may change after the end of next month... right?

Comment: @TOOGAM I know.  I installed Win 10 on a computer that previously has Win XP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a single (portable) drive and booting it on different computers can work.

There is a catch though: You need an OS with all the right drivers, or the ability to detect and select the right drivers at boot time. In practice this means that it will work fine except when you run Windows (which is very fast but no flexible in its boot process).